# How to display a FileField that doesn't exist on the model - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using djangorestframework==3.0.3

So I would like to display an upload field that doesn't exist on the model. I don't want to save the uploaded file to the model. I want to handle it separately. I get this error with the code below  'XYZModelName' object has no attribute 'upload_file'.

```
class XYZSerializer(MyParentSerializer):

    upload_file = serializers.FileField(use_url=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.XYZModelName
        fields = ('name', 'active', 'upload_file')

class XYZModelName(TrackedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The error makes since as I don't have upload_file as an attribute on the model. I don't want upload_file on the model.

How do I show the field in the browseable api?

I've also tried creating custom fields overriding the to_internal_value and to_representation methods.

Comment: I'm assuming you're getting the error when trying to POST to the API to create a new XYZ object?

Comment: No I am just going to the route. So it's happening with a GET. I would think that this will happen with a POST as well.

Comment: but you say you don't want to `save the uploaded file`. If you're doing GET, what do you really want to achieve? Have the serializer output an URL to some external file, that is not part of the model?

Comment: Yes sorry, I do want to save the file to the disk but I don't want to save the file info in the database in a column within my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define a function on the model that returns the URL (it needs to be somehow related to your object obviously)

```
def get_file_url(self):
    return settings.STORAGE_LOCATION + 'some/path/' + str(self.pk) + '.png'
```

And then you can use that in your serializer, like:

```
upload_file = serializers.FileField(source='get_file_url')
```

To save the file during POST, you'll need to override the `create` method of your serializer, like:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    file = validated_data['upload_file']
    # save file code here
    del validated_data['upload_file']
    return XYZ.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: That won't create an upload field for the upload_file attribute, will it? I was going to manage the file by overriding the save method on the model. Is there a better way/place to manage the file on the POST?

Comment: no it won't, try now, this should be more or less fully functional, though not tested.